# Getting error on importing Sparkle Framwork for Xcode 5

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sparkle

I am downloaded Sparkle 1.5 from git hub. when i am copying it into my existing project it is giving following error.Can anybody tell me what is the reason of this

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/Sparkle.framework/Versions/A/Sparkle
  Referenced from: /Users/SS/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Capture_It-dswmsaclkiypqrbcnbaymxlwxxgo/Build/Products/Debug/Capture It.app/Contents/MacOS/Capture It
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Have you imported the library correctly?

Comment: Clue: `image not found`.